# How to retrieve a control's viewmodel after creation?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a Window and a UserControl. The UserControl creates its own viewmodel like this:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="UiInteraction.UserControl3"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UiInteraction"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:UserControl3Vm/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding String1}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

When the Window instantiates the UserControl I want the viewmodel of the Window to be able to retrieve the viewmodel of the UserControl.

```xml
<Window x:Class="UiInteraction.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UiInteraction"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVm/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl3 DataContext="{Binding UserControl3Vm, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

The Window's viewmodel has a publicly settable property of type object. With the DataContext binding I'm expecting that once the UserControl3 is created the value of its DataContext (which is a reference to its viewmodel) would be assigned to the UserControl3Vm property on the Window's viewmodel.

What actually happens is that the Window.UserControl3Vm property setter is called with the value null.

Why is this happening, and what is the best way to achieve what I have in mind?

I know it would be easier to instantiate the viewmodel for the UserControl as a property on the viewmodel for the Window and have the UserControl simply bind onto that, (and that would also minimize the coupling of the views to their viewmodels). But where I work they are a bit nutty and prefer view first MVVM instead of viewmodel first, so I'm looking for the most decoupled way to enable viewmodels to collaberate effectively when the viewmodels are instead created by their views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it will work to use a `OneWayToSource` binding without some code-behind.

Initially, your `UserControl.DataContext` is set to an instance of `UserControl3vm`, however you are replacing `UserControl3vm` with a Binding, so your original `UserControl3vm` is no longer referenced anywhere.

For a `OneWayToSource` binding to work, you'd have to first set the `DataContext` to your `OneWayToSource` binding, and then set the binding's Source to a new instance of `UserControl3vm` from inside your UserControl.

If I remember correctly, you can obtain the binding using [BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbindingexpression.aspx), and update it's [DataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.dataitem%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property. You can't simply set the `UserControl.DataContext` because it would overwrite your `OneWayToSource` binding.

Personally I would just do it in the code-behind the `Loaded` event

If they're insisting on View-First MVVM, then the View is controlling the application flow and I don't see any reason why you should keep application logic out of the View's code-behind.

So just set your `Window.DataContext.UserControl3Vm` property to `UserControl3.DataContext` in the Loaded event :)

```
<Window x:Name="MyWindow"
        Loaded="MyWindow_Loaded" 
        ... >
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl3 x:Name="MyUserControl" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((MainWindowVm)MyWindow.DataContext).UserControl3Vm 
        = MyUserControl.DataContext;
}
```

Comment: That's some nasty coupling going on there. The UserControl view would have to know the concrete type of the viewmodel used by the view which is hosting it. What if the UserControl were hosted by a variety of different views? It would then need to interogate the type of its owning view in order to be able to assign its viewmodel reference to the viewmodel of its owner.

Comment: @Neutrino The `Loaded` event should go in the code-behind the `Window`, not the `UserControl`, so it will only need to reference it's own ViewModel's datatype. I'll update the code sample to make that easier to see.

Comment: Sorry, I was being dim. Yes that works pretty well. I don't even need to use the Loaded event, I can do it right after the call to InitializeComponent in the Window constructor.

Comment: And I think you are right about the BindingExpression replacing the UserControl's DataContext too. So I'll mark this as the answer although if anyone's got a way of making it work in the XAML file I'd still love to see it.

Comment: You don't need to name the window to reference it inside its own class. Just do: this.UserControl3Vm = MyUserControl.DataContext;

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht You're right that you can use `this` instead of naming the Window, although `this.UserControl3Vm` won't work since `UserControl3Vm` is a property on the `Window.DataContext`, not the Window :)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in XAML using some workaround(to hack access of `DataContext` of host element). The approach is mentioned [here](http://www.wpfmentor.com/2008/11/adding-bindings-to-clr-properties-in.html). It uses [Freezables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx).

The XAML is

```
<Window x:Class="VM2VMBindingInXaml.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:VM2VMBindingInXaml.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM2VMBindingInXaml.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Window.Resources>
             <vm:UserControl1ViewModel x:Key="childVM"></vm:UserControl1ViewModel>
        <vm:DataResource x:Key="childVmBinding" BindingTarget="{Binding ElementName=child, Path=DataContext}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Name="mainViewModel" >
            <vm:MainWindowViewModel.ChildViewModel>
                <vm:DataResourceBinding DataResource="{StaticResource childVmBinding}">

                </vm:DataResourceBinding>
            </vm:MainWindowViewModel.ChildViewModel>
        </vm:MainWindowViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <vw:UserControl1 x:Name="child" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=childVM}}">
        </vw:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```